# Gitlab Laravel PHPUnit test runner warning

Tags: laravel, phpunit, php-8.1

When I made Laravel application upgrades to Laravel 10, PHP 8.1, and PHPUnit 10, I am encountering an error at the end of the update process. All tests run successfully, but this error occurs at the end.
[image: full tests]
Here is how phpunit.xml looks like:
[image: XML file]
What I need to update to work again normally and do not show this failed job at the end?

Comment: And what is the failed test? You just upload an output without any meaningful content...

Comment: None of the tests failed. You can take a look at the changed first photo.

Comment: Do you need some more info?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How to make it work:

Add this line into .gitlab-ci.yml

```
before_script:
  - cp .platform/gitlab/my_php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/99-xdebug.ini
```

in the root of the file, work as well if added at some stage, but this is more clean for me.

Then make `my_php.ini` in `.platform/gitlab` folder with this content:

```
xdebug.mode=coverage
```

And all works fine, again :)

Comment: I mean... Read the documentation... How do you expect phpunit to coverage if you do not tell xdebug to be able to? The documentation is explicit in both places...

Comment: in an older version of phpunit it works well. If you know that why you do not tell me?? It's much easy to criticize people than help them.

Comment: Sorry, I am tired of people asking the same questions, a simple google: `xdebug.mode=coverage has to be set` returns this as the first result: https://travis-ci.community/t/warning-xdebug-mode-coverage-has-to-be-set-in-php-ini/10919 (from 2020.......)

Comment: I tried for a few days to google it but didn't find a way how to set it up in GitLab. And shared here with others who had the same issue easy make it.